# does doc2vec(gensim) infer_vector needs window-size padded sentence?

Tags: gensim, doc2vec

According to the original paper [Distributed Representations of Sentences and Documents](https://cs.stanford.edu/~quocle/paragraph_vector.pdf), the inference on unseen paragraph can be done by

*training “the inference stage” to get paragraph vectors **D** for new
paragraphs (never seen before) by adding more columns
in **D** and gradient descending on **D** while holding **W, U, b**
fixed*

This *inference stage* can be done in gensim by `infer_vector()`.
If I have `window = 5` for doc2vec model, and attempts to infer paragraph with whose some sentences are `len(sentence) < 5`.

such as :

`model = Doc2Vec(window=5)
paragraph = [['I', 'am', 'groot'], ['I', 'am', 'groot', 'I', 'am', 'groot']]
model.infer_vector(paragraph)`

In this case, should I pre-pad my inferring vector with special NULL word symbol so that all length of sentences in the paragraph should be bigger than window size ?

such as :

`paragraph = [['I', 'am', 'groot', NULL, NULL], ['I', 'am', 'groot', 'I', 'am', 'groot']]`

Answer (score 2):

You never need to do any explicit padding.

In the default and common `Doc2Vec` modes, if there's not enough context on either side of a focal word, the effective `window` simply shrinks on that side to match what is available.

(In the non-default `dm=1, dm_concat=1` mode, there's automatic padding when necessary. But this mode results in larger, slower models requiring a lot more data to train, and whose value isn't very clear in any proven settings. That mode is unlikely to get good results except for advanced users with a lot of data and ability to tinker with non-default parameters.)

Answer (score 0):

I found that gensim automatically pre-pads documents at both training and inferring stage.

[gensim.models.doc2vec.train_document_dm_concat](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/_modules/gensim/models/doc2vec.html)

```
    null_word = model.vocab['\0']
    pre_pad_count = model.window
    post_pad_count = model.window
    padded_document_indexes = (
        (pre_pad_count * [null_word.index])  # pre-padding
        + [word.index for word in word_vocabs if word is not None]  # elide out-of-Vocabulary words
        + (post_pad_count * [null_word.index])  # post-padding
    )
```

Comment: That's only in the slow, large-model, non-default `dm_concat=1` mode. In other modes there's no padding, just a reduction of the effective `window` to what's available.